# Make widget drag'n'drop able and allow to scroll view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Assume you have a ListView with some `Widgets` to get scrolled up and down. Additionally, the Widget should be draggable

May I tell the `Draggable`, that a drag should start, if the user **taps longer**. And a scroll should happen, if the user **taps shorter**?

Code of the `Draggable`:

```
Draggable<EItem>(
                  data: widget.eItemStore.state,
                  dragAnchorStrategy: pointerDragAnchorStrategy,
                  feedback: feedbackWidget,
                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints( maxWidth: 350, minHeight: 30 ),
                      child: innerWidget(context, widget.eItemStore.state)),
                  onDragStarted: () {
                    // print('Drag started');
                  });
```

This problem appears **solely on touch devices**, since on a mouse pointer device, users may use the scroll wheel to scroll.

Comment: What if you wrap the inner widget in a `GestureDetector` and use `onLongPressStart` which sets some variable (you'll need a `StatefulWidget` now) to `true` (and `onLongPressEnd` should set it to `false`), and have an if statement so that if the variable is true, wrap it in `Draggable`, and otherwise, don't. (Hopefully that makes sense)

Comment: Thx! Might be an option. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a widget especially to handle this case [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html). It will allow to reorder only on long press and allow scroll on shorter press

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(50, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    final Color oddItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.05);
    final Color evenItemColor = colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(0.15);

    return ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index += 1)
          ListTile(
            key: Key('$index'),
            tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
            title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx! In this case probably not applicable. The items may be moved from one column to another column. Reordering isn't possible at all. I may insert a handle Widget in the lower right of the widget's box and start the drag'n'drop if the user taps the handle.